# Where is the definition of libc++ ios_base::clear?

Tags: c++, libc++

In the libc++ header, `<ios>`, available to view here:

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/ios

there are two declarations of `class ios_base`, the "libcpp version" has a `clear` method, `ios_base::clear()` whilst the other does not. This is a public method and is not described here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base

Further, in the implementation referenced above, `basic_ios::clear()` calls `ios_base::clear()` but it appears to not be defined anywhere. In libstdc++ it is implemented as can be seen here:

http://repo.or.cz/w/official-gcc.git/blob/HEAD:/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_ios.tcc

So my questions are:

1) why is there a public `ios_base::clear()` method in libc++?

2) where can I find how `basic_ios::clear()` is implemented in libc++?

Comment: The implementation of `ios_base::clear()` is in this file: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/src/ios.cpp#L265

Comment: Thanks. I prob. should have found that myself. I suppose having the `clear()` method as member of `ios_base` is something the lib++ implementers found convenient and could, and so did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can blame me for this.

I've found that throwing an exception is something that is not small in code size.  And so I like to outline functions that throw into sources when possible.

`basic_ios::clear()` must sometimes throw an exception, and is also a template class.  If I correctly recall, this annoyed me, as the `rdstate` clearly does not depend upon the `basic_ios` template parameters: `CharT, Traits`.  So I implemented `rdstate` down in the base class (`ios_base`), so that any associated non-inlined code could be shared by all instantiations of `basic_ios`.

As [sty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56338/sth) correctly pointed out, `ios_base::clear()` is implemented in src/ios.cpp.  It is declared `protected` in `ios_base`, and then `basic_ios::clear()` is just an inline forwarding to this common implementation.

In a nutshell:  The "why" is a code size optimization.

Comment: So kinda like SCARY iterators, but a different function.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  This was written before I knew what SCARY was.  But the thought was the same:  push code out to depending on as few template parameters as possible (especially code that should be outlined).  With SCARY iterators there is a real functional benefit.  But here it was intended as purely a code size optimization.